# 2.4GHz Works But Not 5GHz On Linksys WRT1200AC And OpenWrt

Tags: linux, openwrt

I have the above make and model router with OpenWrt version 23.05.02 on it, and both radios on, one with SSID "HAL9000" and the 5GHz as "HAL9000-FM". The 2.4GHz works like a champ, never so much as a hiccup. But while the 5GHz can be seen, when you try to connect, it'll connect and try to get its IP address but it times out. The same type problem occurs if on the computer I try to set a permanent IP address.

I recently bought a new phone that sees both, and if I go to a bar with Wi-Fi it'll work on both "the-bar" and their 5GHz, "bar-name_5G", just peachy. So, I know it's the router that is not right, not the phone. At home, the phone sees both radios as does a Fire TV Cube and two desktops. But they can only use the 2.4GHz.

Comment: Did you configure the 5 GHz access point to be part of your LAN bridge?

Comment: You would be better asking on `https://forum.openwrt.org/c/general/6`

Comment: What is the signal quality at 5 GHz? It is less penetrating than the lower band. Wavemon, https://github.com/uoaerg/wavemon, for example, would show that.

Comment: After posting, I did solve it. What was wrong was the /etc/config/wireless file. The encryption protocol were different with the 5GHZ transmitter having a typo from the original install. Now the 5GHZ works like a champ. Once I fixed the typo. perfect. I found out about the config file by a bunch of web searching.